# Sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that is not a cauchy-sequence, but $(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ a null sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, cauchy-sequences

I'm learning about cauchy sequences which is why I want to know if someone could give me a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that is not a cauchy-sequence, but $(x_{n+1}-x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a null sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic example
$$ x_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j}.$$
It does not converge, is thus not a Cauchy-sequence, but $x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ is a Cauchy sequence.